# Event handler for ObjectContext.SaveChanges event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My requirement is to update UpdatedDate property of the object whenever `ObjectContext.SaveChanges` method is called and for this I tried to attach event handler for savechanges event where I want to find the object that is being updated and update its UpdateDate property, but I am not finding the way to find the object that is getting updated.

Any idea? Am I doing the correct thing to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could look in the `ObjectStateManager`

something like this:

```
private void context_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = (ObjectContext)sender;
    var lst = context.ObjectStateManager
                  .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified); 

    foreach(var item in lst)
    { 
      var entity = item.Entity;
       // TODO: set values here:
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It worked greatly! Is there any predefined way like your answer to set the value of any of the property? Like I want to set the UpdatedDate value of the object being updated, or Reflection is the only way?

Comment: Np :) I would suggets you expand the entities that need to be updated with an interface (maybe `IUpdateEntity` or something) you can use in your loop. something like: `var entity = item.Entity as IUpdateEntity`

Comment: Yeah, that way came to my mind but fortunately reflection fulfilled the requirement more easily :) And now everything is working awesome!

Comment: I have posted one more question related to this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952457/current-user-identity-in-objectcontext-savingchanges, if you have any answer for this