# Current user identity in ObjectContext.SavingChanges

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, httpcontext

I am using `ObjectContext.SavingChanges` event to update CreatedDate/UpdatedDate columns based on the object state like this

```
partial void OnContextCreated()
{
   //Extension of the Command Timeout to avoid processing problems.
   CommandTimeout = 600; //Time in seconds

   this.SavingChanges += new EventHandler(Entities_SavingChanges);
}

protected void Entities_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var addedObjects = this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added);
   foreach (var addedObject in addedObjects)
   {
      var propertyInfo = addedObject.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedDate");
      if (propertyInfo != null)
      {
         propertyInfo.SetValue(addedObject.Entity, DateTime.UtcNow, null);
      }
    }

    var modifiedObjects = this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
    foreach (var modifiedObject in modifiedObjects)
    {
       var propertyInfo = modifiedObject.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("UpdatedDate");
       if (propertyInfo != null)
       {
          propertyInfo.SetValue(modifiedObject.Entity, DateTime.UtcNow, null);
       }
    }
}
```

I have two more columns CreatedUser and UpdatedUser.

Is there any way to update those using current user name from context?

Ofcource, `System.HttpContext.Current` is null here as this is my separate class library project, which I access through WCF service.

Comment: HttpContext.Current will not be null because the code is in a different dll.

Comment: No, HttpContext.Current is not null because the code is in a different DLL. HttpContext.Current is null because this code is running inside a WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

If this code resides in a WCF service that you consume from your ASP.NET MVC application you could send the current username as parameter to the method you are invoking.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question to make it more clear. I am attaching event to ObjectContext so this is called whenever ObjectContext.SaveChanges method is called. So this is something generic thing I am doing for all  the objects saving.

Comment: Oh and the code does not reside inside the web service, it is a separate library project. Web service uses this library project's reference

Comment: So you are calling a Web Service? The fact that this web service uses a class library project is irrelevant. The important thing is that you are calling a WCF webservice from your MVC application and want to *flow* the current user to it, right?

Comment: Well that's your problem. HttpContext.Current will be null in your WCF project. As I already suggested you in my answer you could pass the username as parameter to your method.

Comment: But which method? I am exposing number of methods those add or insert records to the database of different object types and whenever any entry is made to the database I want it to update either CreatedUser or UdpatedUser column with the current user before saving it. So to pass username from all the methods of service???

Comment: Various options exists in this case. For example you could send the username of the currently authenticated user as a custom header: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-header-to-every-wcf-calls